# Listen to URL change in opened window

Tags: javascript, facebook, cross-domain

If I open a window (with `window.open`), can I detect when its URL changes (to a specific one), given that:

- The initial URL for the window is on another domain (Facebook, to be precise)
- The URL I'm interested in detecting is too

I need this for authentication. [See "Desktop apps" at the bottom of this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/).

Comment: Is this running in a desktop app embedded browser? This is important as in regular web browsers you're not allowed to read back from the window object (returned by `window.open`) if it's on a different domain, but in a dektop web client control the rules may be more lax.

Comment: Are you embedding the browser into your desktop app?

Comment: It's in a browser, but I find the desktop app more convenient than redirecting to an actual URL in my site (because there are some checks which makes testing with a local version annoying). Still, that's possible if this fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the new url resides on a domain not considered equal to your own by the Same Origin Policy, then this will impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way I've found is to simply keep polling the window's `location.href` (using `setTimeout`), but it's hardly elegant.

**Update**: It doesn't work. I can `console.log(newWin.location)` just fine, but when I try to access `href` or `hash` I get cross-domain security errors.